# Looping over list multiple times

Tags: python, iteration, genome

Is it possible to iterate through a list multiple times? basically, I have a list of strings and I am looking for the longest superstring. Each of the strings in the list has some overlap of at least half of their length and they are all the same size.I want to see if the superstring I'm adding onto startswith or endswith each of the sequences in the list and when I find a match I want to add that element to my superstring, delete the element from the list and then loop over it again and again until my list is empty.

```
sequences=['ATTAGACCTG','CCTGCCGGAA','AGACCTGCCG',''GCCGGAATAC']
halfway= len(sequences[0])/2
genome=sequences[0]     # this is the string that will be added onto throughout the loop
sequences.remove(sequences[0]) 


for j in range(len(sequences)):
    for sequence in sequences:
        front=[]
        back=[]
        for i in range(halfway,len(sequence)):

            if genome.endswith(sequence[:i]):
                genome=genome+sequence[i:] 
                sequences.remove(sequence)

            elif genome.startswith(sequence[-i:]):
                genome=sequence[:i]+genome  
                sequences.remove(sequence)
'''
            elif not genome.startswith(sequence[-i:]) or not genome.endswith(sequence[:i]):

                sequences.remove(sequence)      # this doesnt seem to work want to get rid of 
                                                #sequences that are in the middle of the string and 
                                                 #already accounted for 
'''
```

this works when I dont use the final elif statement and gives me the correct answer ATTAGACCTGCCGGAATAC. However, when I do this with a larger list of strings I am still left with strings in the list that I expected to be empty. Also is the last loop even necessary if I am only looking for strings to add onto the front and back of the superstring (genome in my code).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you are looking for a more helpful answer, you must write a more helpful question: include your code and address specific concerns.

Comment: If you have a loop, you can always add another loop entirely containing the first loop. Then the outer loop can decide how many times the inner loop should repeat.

Comment: I added the outside loop like you said so that it would loop as many times as the length of the list, is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: That looks like you've got it.  To account for the fully contained substrings try using `in`  either at the beginning, or end of your inner `for` loop.  `if sequence in genome:`  This will replace what you are trying to do in that second `elif`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sequences=['ATTAGACCTG','CCTGCCGGAA','AGACCTGCCG','GCCGGAATAC']
sequences.reverse()
genome = sequences.pop(-1)     # this is the string that will be added onto throughout the loop

unrelated = []

while(sequences):
    sequence = sequences.pop(-1)
    if sequence in genome: continue
    found=False
    for i in range(3,len(sequence)):
        if genome.endswith(sequence[:i]):
            genome=genome+sequence[i:]
            found = True
            break
        elif genome.startswith(sequence[-i:]):
            genome=sequence[:i]+genome  
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        unrelated.append(sequence)

print(genome)
#ATTAGACCTGCCGGAATAC
print(sequences)
#[]
print(unrelated)
#[]
```

I do not know if you are guaranteed to not have multiple unrelated sequences in the same batch, so I allowed for the unrelated.  If that is not necessary, feel free to remove.

Python's handling of deleting from the front of a `list` is very inefficient, so I reversed the list and pull from the back.  The reversal might not be necessary depending on the full data (it is with your example data).

I pop from the `sequences` `list` while there are sequences available to avoid removing elements from a `list` while iterating through it.  I then check to see if it is already in the final genome.  If it is not then I go into checking the `endswith` / `beginswith` checks.  If a match is found, slice it into genome; set found flag; break out of the `for` loop

If the sequence is not already contained and a partial match is not found, it gets put into `unrelated`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up solving it, I realized that all you need to do is find out which string is the start of the superstring, since we know that the sequences have an overlap of 1/2 or more I found which half wasn't contained in any of the sequences. From here I looped over a list the amount of times equal to the length of the list and looked for sequences in which the ending of the genome matched the beginning of the appropriate sequence. When I found this I added the sequence onto the genome(superstring) and then removed this sequence and continued iterating through the list. When working with a list of 50 sequences that have a length of 1000 this code takes around .806441 to run

```
def moveFirstSeq(seqList): # move the first sequence in genome to the end of list 
    d={}
    for seq in seqList:
        count=0
        for seq1 in seqList:

            if seq==seq1:
                pass
            if seq[0:len(seq)/2] not in seq1:
                count+=1
                d[seq]= count

    sorted_values=sorted(d.values())
    first_sequence=''
    for k,v in d.items():
        if v==sorted_values[-1]:
            first_sequence=k
            seqList.remove(first_sequence)

            seqList.append(first_sequence)

    return seqList


seq= moveFirstSeq(sequences)  
genome = seq.pop(-1)   # added first sequence to genome and removed from list 

for j in range(len(sequences)):   # looping over the list amount of times equal to the length of the sequence list  
    for sequence in sequences:

        for i in range(len(sequence)/2,len(sequence)):

            if genome.endswith(sequence[:i]):
                genome=genome+sequence[i:]  # adding onto the superstring and 
                sequences.remove(sequence) #removing it from the sequence list 

print genome , seq
```